# mongodb: unreasonable slow query, with index and simple documents

Tags: python, mongodb

I am using python and mongodb, now I need to query documents from database and save some information from the documents, now my code is :

```
for trips in trip.find({},{'latlng_start':1, 'latlng_end':1, 'trip_data':1, 'trip_id':1}).batch_size(500):
    orig_coord = trips['latlng_start']['coordinates']
    dest_coord = trips['latlng_end']['coordinates']
    cell_start = citymap.find({"trips_orig": {"$exists": True},"cell_latlng":{"$geoIntersects":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":orig_coord}}}})
    cell_end = citymap.find({"trips_dest": {"$exists": True},"cell_latlng":{"$geoIntersects":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":dest_coord}}}})

    if cell_start.count() == 1 and cell_end.count() == 1 and cell_start[0]['big_cell8']['POI'] != {} and cell_end[0]['big_cell8']['POI'] != {}:
        try:
            labels_raw.append(purpose_mapping[trips['trip_data']['purpose']])           
            user_ids_raw.append(int(trips['trip_id'][:10]))         
            venue_feature_start.append([cell_start[0]['big_cell8']['POI'], orig_coord])
            venue_feature_end.append([cell_end[0]['big_cell8']['POI'], dest_coord]) 
        except:
            continue

    else:
        continue
```

I have assigned 2dsphere index to the collection citymap and the indexes of this collection are:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "CitySeg2014.grid750"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "latlng" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "latlng_2dsphere",
        "ns" : "CitySeg2014.grid750",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "cell_latlng" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "cell_latlng_2dsphere",
        "ns" : "CitySeg2014.grid750",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "trips_dest_text_trips_orig_text",
        "ns" : "CitySeg2014.grid750",
        "weights" : {
            "trips_dest" : 1,
            "trips_orig" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 2
    }
]
```

The problem is that, although there are only 47000 *trips* and the citymap contains only 11600 documents, the query takes about 3000 seconds!!! But this morning when I run the same program it takes about 800 seconds. I have no idea why this would happen. Any idea to improve the efficiency?

Comment: As you are saying that at different time of the day the load is varying try and see there is no one else using mongodb for load testing etc., also see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416150/mongodb-python-very-slow-simple-query?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095010/mongodb-slow-query-even-with-index?rq=1 basically make sure you dont have too many indexes

Comment: Use the mongodb integrated profiler to pinpoint *which* query is slow. The first query reads all data anyway, the second starts with `$exists` which is about the worst way you can start a query, since *metainformation is not part of the index*, **plus** it has ultra-low selectivity. In fact, if you need `$exists`, you might want to review your data model, but you should probably move it to the end. Use the profile and `.explain()`.